# Vscode working Docker C#/postgres app fails in devcontainer extension with generic "Error: An error occurred setting up the container."

Tags: postgresql, docker, visual-studio-code, vscode-devcontainer

I have a 100% working docker based C#/Postgres app.

The project structure is like this

```
.
├── ./amaranth
├── ./amaranth.Tests
└── ./amaranth.sln
```

./amaranth/docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: app
    depends_on:
      - db
    env_file: .env
    ports:
      - 8000:5000
      - 8001:5001

    volumes:
      - ./sslcert:/https:ro

  db:
    container_name: db
    image: postgres:14.3
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - postgres-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    env_file: .env
    ports:
      - 5432:5432

volumes:
  postgres-data:
```

I successfully run the app by running `cd amaranth` then `docker-compose --env-file .env up`. So I decided to change the app to a vscode docker devcontainer. The changes were simple. I added a `.devcontainer` folder to the root of the project.

This is the tree of the `.devcontainer` directory:

```
.
├── devcontainer.env
├── devcontainer.json
├── docker-compose.yml
```

The only changes that I made to the `docker-compose.yml` file were minimal to account for new locations etc...:

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  app:
    build:
      context: ../amaranth/
      dockerfile: ../amaranth/Dockerfile
    container_name: app
    depends_on:
      - db
    env_file: devcontainer.env

    volumes:
      - ./sslcert:/https

    # Overrides default command so things don't shut down after the process ends.
    command: sleep infinity

    # Runs app on the same network as the database container, allows "forwardPorts" in devcontainer.json function.
    network_mode: service:db
    
    # Uncomment the next line to use a non-root user for all processes.
    # user: vscode

    # Use "forwardPorts" in **devcontainer.json** to forward an app port locally. 
    # (Adding the "ports" property to this file will not forward from a Codespace.)

  db:
    container_name: db
    image: postgres:14.3
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - postgres-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    env_file: devcontainer.env
      
    # Add "forwardPorts": ["5432"] to **devcontainer.json** to forward PostgreSQL locally.
    # (Adding the "ports" property to this file will not forward from a Codespace.)

volumes:
  postgres-data:
```

So I launched this with the simple "Reopen in Container" prompt that the docker devcontainer vscode extension gives me, it loaded for a long time with `Starting Dev Container (show log)`, then failed with this really generic error `Error: An error occurred setting up the container.`. Here's the screenshot of the error:
[image]

The Dockerfile that the docker-compose.yml file references looks like this:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build-env
WORKDIR /workspace

# Copy everything
COPY . ./
# Restore as distinct layers
RUN dotnet restore
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o out

# Build runtime image
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0
WORKDIR /workspace
COPY --from=build-env /workspace/out .
COPY nuget.config /
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "amaranth.dll"]
```

It's contents didn't change between the regular docker version and devcontainer version. What is the problem here? Why can't I run this docker C#/postgres app in a docker devcontainer? Is there just a simple way to get clear error logs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks to be the Dockerfile Location in .devcontainer/docker-compose.yml

In build you set the context to the amaranth dir. So no need to add the path to dockerfile:

Try this for the top.

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  app:
    build:
      context: ../amaranth
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: app
    ...
```